# Why is my get_forecast index different from the index of my endog and exog variables?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to forecast a univariate time series and when I'm using the get_forecast or forecast function for SARIMAX from statsmodels, the outputted index is a RangeIndex instead of a DateTimeIndex like my inputs' indexes are

It works fine, however, when I use the get_prediction function to see the validity of my model

See picture:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the DateTimeIndex to be 1-01-14,2-01-14, etc. And it fixed the issue.